# VBA macro in excel 2010 32 Bit mode

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have a excel sheet which saved using Excel 2010 64 Bit. It has a code as follows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 17 Then
Dim iRet As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B2").Value2) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Clear the values in columns
    Range("S:AZ").ClearContents

    arr = Split(Target, ",")
    Range("S15:AZ15").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("S15", Cells(15, UBound(arr) + 19)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr))
    Range("AZ1").Value2 = Target

    Worksheets("MasterPage").Range("X3:X1000").ClearContents
    Worksheets("MasterPage").Range("X3:X1000").NumberFormat = "@"
    Worksheets("MasterPage").Range("X3:X" & UBound(arr) + 3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
End If
```

End Sub

If I am trying to execute the saved file in Excel 2010 32 Bit mode it want execute. Can anybody suggest the reason. Thanks

Comment: How are you executing? is there any error messages? Any further info you have can help us help you

Comment: I am assigning selected values to a cell range. The values are not applying to cells.No error messages

Comment: Have you stepped through your code at each point to check it's running as expected? You can always break it down into constituent parts to help with debugging

Comment: Even the debug points are not hitting

Answer (score 0):

Your comments suggests that either this specific event isn't being triggered for some reason or no code at all is getting triggered (I know Excel can prevent code execution by default sometimes so lookout for that)

Try seeing if any code gets executed at all. You could try hooking up a macro to a button to explicitly fire the code to help you work out if that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried on Excel 2010 32-bit and it ran through with no problem.

A few questions:

1. Did you turn off Application.EnableEvents at some point in your code?
2. There is no End Sub in the code you provided, I'm assuming this was lost in copying and pasting to SU, but double-check that.
3. Will anything run on the worksheet_change event?

Additionally, I would make a few changes to your code to help it run more efficiently. Currently everytime your procedure changes another cell it runs again. I added a few lines to turn off event triggers and turn them on again to prevent things running multiple times.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 17 Then
        Dim iRet As Integer
        Dim arr As Variant
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("B2").Value2) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'Clear the values in columns
        Range("S:AZ").ClearContents

        arr = Split(Target, ",")
        Range("S15:AZ15").NumberFormat = "@"
        Range("S15", Cells(15, UBound(arr) + 19)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr))
        Range("AZ1").Value2 = Target

        Worksheets("MasterPage").Range("X3:X1000").ClearContents
        Worksheets("MasterPage").Range("X3:X1000").NumberFormat = "@"
        Worksheets("MasterPage").Range("X3:X" & UBound(arr) + 3) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```